# Deleting large no of folders in one go

Tags: linux, bash, centos, delete-file, rm

I have a list of 1M folders/directory, which I need to delete on my system. What is the best possible way to do it ?

I am looking for best possible solution, which will not consume lot of time, as I a have some processes which will be waiting for its completion.

PS: I can put all folders name in a file, if required, or do it in batch, if we can not do it in one go.

Comment: This may better fit to [unix.se](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/46852/doing-an-rm-rf-on-a-massive-directory-tree-takes-hours

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `xargs` tool. It will read all folder names from the file and call a command - in this case `rmdir`.

```
xargs rmdir < list_of_folders
```

If you are sure you can delete non-empty folders, use `rm -r` instead of `rmdir`.

I think this is about the fastest you can get. `rmdir` will act as fast as it can (simple OS call), and using `xargs` ensures that you do not create 1M separate processes.

You may exploit that there are no "nested" directories in your list.
By that, if you have three folder `a/` `a/b/` and `a/c/`, and `b/` and `c/` are the only entries in `a/`, then you can omit `a/b/` and `a/c/` and just call `rm -r a/`.
But it will not be worth checking that by `ls`, as `ls` will also cost time which you probably won't save.

Answer (score 0):

The [`rm`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rm) command is perfectly capable of handling this. Just give it the list of folders you need to delete ([shell expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html#Shell-Expansions) can save you some time for that matter), and don't forget the `-r` switch.

Exemple using some common expansions:

```
rm -r folder_a src/dir_* app_{logs,src,bin}
```

Comment: He said he has a list of a million directories. Due to a limited length of program arguments (`xargs --show-limits < /dev/null`), a single `rm` call will fail (try `/bin/echo {01..10000000} > /dev/null` within bash). `xargs` will handle this and run as few `rm`s as possible, but as many as required.

Comment: Ah dang, I've mistaken 1M directories for 1K directories... Not quite the same thing innit